# Website Manipulation

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

Can anyone point me in the direction for reading material on sending information to a website form via VFP? I need to create a tool to help the data entry team key information to our website form for more consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find [West Wind Technologies](http://www.west-wind.com/) helpful. Rick's blog deals with these sorts of subjects.

Comment: West Wind is the main most accurate complete source for those wishing to use VFP on the web